# Add right-click menu to tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, right-click

I know that with the Chrome API extensions can create right-click menu items when right-clicked *on the page*. Is there a way to add right-click menus when the user right-clicks *on the top of the tab*? I'm thinking of making an extension that allows you to copy the tab URL when the tab is not in focus.

[image: Showing right-click on the page]
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be useful, but extensions are limited to what they can modify in Chrome's UI, besides the context menu and page\browser actions, they cannot access non-client areas.

Comment: Is this still true now? 6 years later?